# How to select row from two different tables using specific id in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 different tables in db those are like tbl1, tbl2, tbl3 
in these all table have one same columns 'direction'.
tbl1 contain one value either tbl2 or tbl3,
tbl2 contains one value tbl3.
How can I select the rows from tbl1 and tbl2 which contains direction like equal tbl3.

i also include my two table image in this image 2 columns name is same  level_redir now i want which row that have value like hardening
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPoql.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEE6t.png)

please suggest me which query is good for getting row from two different tables in which table columns where dir_redirect = 'hardening'.

Comment: Please include the structure of the tables and the structure you are expecting

Comment: Please include your query which you have tried and table structure

Comment: You need JOIN for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is not clear and you have not included all the table structure its bit difficult to figure out.

Let me help you with generic way

The following query we have joined all the 3 tables based on the common tables with are present in the respective tables. The following query select all the columns from all the 3 tables.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.matching_column = t2.matching_column
JOIN table3 as t3 ON t3.matching_column = t2.matching_column
WHERE t3.column_name = 'Condition';
```

You can select from specific tables by the following

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, t2.col2 FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.matching_column = t2.matching_column
JOIN table3 as t3 ON t3.matching_column = t2.matching_column
WHERE t3.column_name = 'Condition';
```